# Inject external XUL file into tabpanel

Tags: firefox-addon, xul

I was working on an old XUL based add-on and found that there was an `about.xul` file in use.  This file is used from the `about:addons` page if you right-click on the add-on and choose About from the context-menu.  Ok.  The add-on has an icon with its own context-menu which also has an about option, where the about.xul is accessed from a menuitem->oncommand->window.openDialog() .

```
<menuitem label="About" oncommand="window.openDialog( 'chrome://{GUID}/content/about.xul', /* other parameters */);"/>
```

Again, this is fair enough, I can reuse the same XUL file unmodified.  But, these two options may not be as visible for users.  The add-on has an `options.xul` file with some tabbox->tabpanels.  I thought it would be great to reuse the about.xul file a 3rd time, and just add an "About" panel here.

And then I realized, this might not as simple as I thought.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research, trial and error, I added a 3rd `<tab>` and `<tabpanel>`, with just an `<iframe>` inside.

```
<tabs>
    [other tabs]
    <tab label="About"/>
</tabs>

<tabpanels>
    [other tabpanels]
    <tabpanel>
        <iframe src="chrome://{GUID}/content/about.xul" flex="1"/>
    </tabpanel>
</tabpanel>
```

This actually worked, and was far simpler than I initially thought.

However, in my particular case, the CSS needs to be dynamically modified so that if the About page is called from the Options panel, the style matches the Options panel rather than the default.

Now all that is left is to effectively recreate the default "About" dialog page displayed when there is no aboutURL defined.  This is an exercise in writing basic XUL code and dynamically applying CSS as needed.  All of this is made possible from learning to inject XUL into XUL - a single page reused from 3 calling contexts.  This further sets the stage to dynamically generate almost the entire page, which has prepared me for the migration towards SDK and beyond.